# Identify HP Array Logical Drive From Windows

Tags: windows-server-2003, raid, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

Probably something simple, but I'm trying to identify which logical drive in my HP Server's Array relates to a particular disk presented in Windows Server 2003.

So I have a Proliant DL580 G5 server with two RAID controllers. The controller in question is a Smart Array P400, which has 8 disks, split into 4 Arrays (A,B,C,D) each with a RAID 1 logical drive. The server is reporting a disk failure on one of the logical drives, and I would like to backup the files before replacing the failed disk.

What I thought would be a simple task is proving a bit of a pain. How do I identify which windows 'disk' relates to each of the logical drives in the RAID Array? I can't find any properties in diskmgmt.msc that relate to properties in ACU. Whilst I have an idea which one it is, I can't be sure.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have the HP management utilities installed? Download the [ProLiant Support Pack for Windows 2003](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=3562405&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=3454575&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=1005#78221) (or the [64-bit variant](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=3562405&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=3454575&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=1113#78221)).

This will be helpful in providing general management and health monitoring of the system. At the very least, you can acquire the information you're seeking by installing the [Array Configuration Utility CLI (command line interface)](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=3454575&prodNameId=3562405&swEnvOID=1005&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-0a7bc9292e014897aa3c79c666) component of the ProLiant Support Pack.

Running a quick command like `ctrl all show config detail` will generate a good amount of controller, array and disk information; including mount points. You'll also see which drives are assigned to which RAID 1 pair and the overall health of each logical drive. Based on this information, you should be able to replace the failed drive seamlessly, but make sure you examine the output first.

```
HP Array Configuration Utility CLI 8.60-8.0
Type "help" for a list of supported commands.
Type "exit" to close the console.

=> ctrl all show config detail

Smart Array P400i in Slot 0 (Embedded)
   Bus Interface: PCI
   Slot: 0
   Serial Number: PH7AMW5213
   Cache Serial Number: PA82C0H9SVC7O6
   RAID 6 (ADG) Status: Disabled
   Controller Status: OK
   Chassis Slot:
   Hardware Revision: Rev D
   Firmware Version: 7.18
   Rebuild Priority: Medium
   Expand Priority: Medium
   Surface Scan Delay: 15 secs
   Surface Scan Mode: Idle
   Wait for Cache Room: Disabled
   Surface Analysis Inconsistency Notification: Disabled
   Post Prompt Timeout: 0 secs
   Cache Board Present: True
   Cache Status: OK
   Accelerator Ratio: 25% Read / 75% Write
   Drive Write Cache: Enabled
   Total Cache Size: 256 MB
   No-Battery Write Cache: Enabled
   Battery/Capacitor Count: 0
   SATA NCQ Supported: True

   Array: A
      Interface Type: SAS
      Unused Space: 0 MB
      Status: OK

      Logical Drive: 1
         Size: 136.7 GB
         Fault Tolerance: RAID 1
         Heads: 255
         Sectors Per Track: 32
         Cylinders: 35132
         Strip Size: 128 KB
         Status: OK
         Array Accelerator: Enabled
         Unique Identifier: 600508B1001032313320202020200001
         Disk Name: \\.\PhysicalDrive0
         Mount Points: C:\ 136.7 GB
         Logical Drive Label: A240AB6BPH7AMW5213     E1C6
         Mirror Group 0:
            physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
         Mirror Group 1:
            physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 146 GB, OK)

      physicaldrive 1I:1:1
         Port: 1I
         Box: 1
         Bay: 1
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SAS
         Size: 146 GB
         Rotational Speed: 10000
         Firmware Revision: HPD1
         Serial Number: BS01P7900S6P0738
         Model: HP      DG146A3516
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 3.0GBPS

      physicaldrive 1I:1:2
         Port: 1I
         Box: 1
         Bay: 2
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SAS
         Size: 146 GB
         Rotational Speed: 10000
         Firmware Revision: HPD1
         Serial Number: BS01P7900PY80737
         Model: HP      DG146A3516
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: Unknown
```

Comment: You, sir, are a star :)

Comment: That is spot on, mapping the mount points to the logical drive was exactly what I was after, and couldn't see this in the GUI for the Array Config Utility. This is my first post, what's the process for marking as correct etc?